# search a word in a pdf file and go to that page using itextsharp in c#

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

i want to identify a word in a PDF document and go to that page which word is available.when i search a word and click a button i want to go to that page.i used below code but i couldn't find the answer.

```
        public List<int> ReadPdfFile(string fileName, String searthText)
    {
        List<int> pages = new List<int>();
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);
            for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();

                string currentPageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
                if (currentPageText.Contains(searthText))
                {
                    pages.Add(page);
                }
            }
            pdfReader.Close();
        }
        return pages;

    }
```

i got the no of pages which the word is used by this.

```
        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String s = textBox1.Text;

        List<int> list1 = ReadPdfFile(dlg.FileName, s);
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count;i++ )
        {
            richTextBox2.Text = list1[i].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: *want to go to that page.* - what do you mean by that.

Comment: when i click the search button i want to scroll down to the page where the certain word is located.

Comment: iTextSharp is a programming library to create and manipulate PDFs. It has no user interface nor does it have any direct capabilities to interact with a user interface. If you have written or are using another library to view a PDF it will be up to that library to perform that actual "scroll down".

Comment: I used Adobe pdf viewer(axAcroPDF) to view pdf documents.there is a find option in the toolbar.but i want to code it manualy.